# Mathematic modeling of an overshot water wheel

Tags: applied-mechanics, modeling, mathematics, building-physics

We're working on a project that require some mechanical engineering and electronics engineering. In this project we've to model this overshot [water wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_wheel) (so the water comes from the left top side and flows over the wheel to a lower place, so that the wheel will spin at a certain velocity).

But we've to get a startup to model this mathematically, we're looking for a so complete model (we're looking for as much as important inputs and as outputs we're looking for the torque and the power of the wheel).

[image]

Comment: Is there an actual question in there anywhere? This is a Q&A site -- we're not going to just sit around and discuss your project in general. That's what [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20403/the-skunk-works) is for.